# Automatic Evaluation Strategy Selection in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

Consider the following function template:

```
template<typename T> void Foo(T)
{
  // ...
}
```

Pass-by-value semantics make sense if `T` happens to be an integral type, or at least a type that's cheap to copy.
Using pass-by-[const]-reference semantics, on the other hand, makes more sense if `T` happens to be an expensive type to copy.

Let's assume for a second that you are writing a library. Ideally, as a library implementer, your job is to provide your consumers with a clean API that is both as generic and efficient as possible. How then, do you provide a generic interface that caters to both types of argument passing strategies?

---

Here is my first attempt at getting this to work:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template<typename T> struct DefaultCondition
{
  enum {value = boost::is_integral<T>::value /* && <other trait(s)> */};
};

template< typename T, class Condition = DefaultCondition<T> > class Select
{
  template<bool PassByValue = Condition::value, class Dummy = void> struct Resolve
  {
    typedef T type;
  };

  template<class Dummy> struct Resolve<false, Dummy>
  {
    typedef const T& type;
  };

  public: typedef typename Resolve<>::type type;
};
```

Typical usage:

```
template<typename T> class EnterpriseyObject
{
  typedef typename Select<T>::type type;

  public: explicit EnterpriseyObject(type)
  {
    // ...
  }
};

struct CustomType {};

void Usage()
{
  EnterpriseyObject<int>(0); // Pass-by-value.
  (EnterpriseyObject<CustomType>(CustomType())); // Pass-by-const-reference.
}
```

This, of course, indirectly breaks implicit template argument deduction for non-class templates:

```
template<typename T> void Foo(typename Select<T>::type)
{
  // ...
}

void Usage()
{
  Foo(0);      // Incomplete.
  Foo<int>(0); // Fine.
}
```

This can be "fixed" with the `Boost.Typeof` library and a macro, a la the `WinAPI`:

```
#define Foo(Arg) ::Foo<BOOST_TYPEOF((Arg))>((Arg))
```

Though this is just a quasi-portable hack.

As you can see, my general approach is not really satisfactory for all cases.

---

As a hobbyist programmer, I neither have real-world experience nor do I have access to production-quality code for reference. I also realize that this might seem like a bad case of premature optimization, but I'm genuinely interested in a couple of things:

1. Do you, or have you used this type of optimization* in the past?
2. Does the `Boost` (or any other public) library already provide similar functionality?
3. If the answer to #1 or #2 is a 'yes' -- how is the non-class template case handled?
4. Are there any obvious pitfalls that I'm not seeing with something like this?
5. Finally, is this even a sane thing to do?

---

* Not profiled. ;)

Comment: Was gonna mention http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/ref.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. All the time. I use it myself.
2. Yes, use [Boost.Utility's Call Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) :)

   Usage would be...

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void foo(boost::call_traits<T>::param_type param)
   {
       // Use param
   }
   ```
3. As far as I know, non-class templates are passed-by-value unless it is faster to not. Thanks to partial template specialization, it can be customized relatively easily.
4. Sorry, didn't really read what you did, it just looked like exactly what I went through a few months ago. Therefore, can't really answer this one. My recommendation is just to read through Boost.Utility.
5. Of course!

Comment: Excellent. Should have looked harder before posting. Thanks so much! ;)